# Convert >< smiley to an image

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex for matching `><`: `/(\\\>\\\<)/`. But nothing happens when I use that regex.

How can I match `><` and turn it into an image?

If you need the whole function to see how I it looks like:

```
function bbcode($string) {

    # GLOBAL
    global $folder_smileys;

    # VARIABLE
    $hashtag = str_replace('|', '', $string);
    $string = nl2br($string);
    $icon_div_1 = '<div class="icon-inplace" style="background-image: url(';
    $icon_div_2 = ');"></div>';


    # ARRAY
    $codes = Array(
        '/\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/' => '<div class="font-bold">\1</div>',
        '/\[i\](.+?)\[\/i\]/' => '<div class="font-italic">\1</div>',
        '/\[s\](.+?)\[\/s\]/' => '<div class="font-strikethrough">\1</div>',
        '/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/' => '<a href="\1" target="_blank">\2</a>',

        '/:\)/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'smiley-1f642.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/;\)/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'smiley-1f609.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/:\//' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'smiley-1f615.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/:\(/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'smiley-1f641.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/:O/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'smiley-1f632.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/:P/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'smiley-1f61b.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/-.-/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'smiley-1f611.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/\^\^/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'smiley-1f604.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/:@/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'smiley-1f621.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/<3/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'symbol-2764.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/O.o/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'smiley-1f924.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/\(Y\)/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'symbol-1f44d-1f3fb.png') . $icon_div_2,
        '/(\\\>\\\<)/' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys.'smiley-1f616.png') . $icon_div_2
    );


    # OUTPUT
    return preg_replace(array_keys($codes), array_values($codes), $string);

}


echo bbcode('><');  // Outputs >< and not as an image
```

Comment: You don't need to think about escaping it.

Comment: put all search strings containing angle brackets at first positions in your replacement list (before items that produce angle brackets). In other words put all square brackets patterns at the end of your array. Other thing: angle brackets are not special characters in regexes, you don't need to escape them. Note that using `array_values` is useless, `$codes` should suffice.

Comment: `/(><)/` and `/(\>\<)/` gives `/div> /div> /div> /div>  /div> /div> /div> /div> /div> /div> /div> /div>` on `:) ;) :O ^^ >< O.o :( :P -.- <3 :@ :/ (Y)`. The image for the other smileys are shown before `/div>`, including the image for `><` but not with `/div>`.

Comment: So it works but you encounter a confliction between conversions.

Comment: Yes but how can I make it not to ruin the other smileys?

Comment: See @CasimiretHippolyte's comment.

Comment: For the majority of these, you could use str_replace instead (with arrays on both sides). It will be a lot faster and requires no escaping

Comment: If you want to avoid conflicts between smileys, start to change your code using `strtr` with an associative array.

Comment: I "must" see some examples because my disability dosen't allow me to understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Besides, what if all those characters are stuck together `:);):O^^><O.o:(:P-.-<3:@:/(Y)` ? Do you look for the same expected output?

Comment: No. I want to keep them separated. It's (as I know today) easier to handle each smiley that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more clear:

```
function bbcode($string) {

    $smileys = [ ':)' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys. 'smiley-1f642.png') . $icon_div_2,
                 ';)' => $icon_div_1 . url($folder_smileys. 'smiley-1f649.png') . $icon_div_2,
                 // etc.
               ];

    $result = strtr($string, $smileys);

    $codes = [
        '~\[b](.+?)\[/b]~s' => '<div class="font-bold">\1</div>',
        '~\[i](.+?)\[/i]~s' => '<div class="font-italic">\1</div>',
        '~\[s](.+?)\[/s]~s' => '<div class="font-strikethrough">\1</div>',
        '~\[url=(.+?)](.+?)\[/url]~s' => '<a href="\1" target="_blank">\2</a>',
    ];

    $result = preg_replace(array_keys($codes), $codes, $result);

    return $result;
}
```

You need to replace the smileys first, otherwise the angle brackets produced by the bold, italic and url bbcodes risk to be overwritten.

You must understand that when you give an array to `preg_replace` (or to `str_replace`, the behaviour is the same), the function takes the first item, proceed to the replacements and produce a new string, then the next item uses this new string and proceeds to the next replacement. To illustrate this behaviour, if you write something like this:

```
$string = 'az';
$rep = [ '~a~' => 'z',
         '~z~' => 'a' ];

echo preg_replace(array_keys($rep), $rep, $string);
```

You will obtain "aa" (cause of the circular replacement: `"az" -> "zz" -> "aa"`).

`strtr` behaves differently and parses the string only once (whatever the number of replacement pairs).

```
$string = 'az';
$rep = [ 'a' => 'z',
         'z' => 'a' ];

echo strtr($string, $rep);
```

It returns "za" (one pass).

Comment: Oh! You mean like that! Now I follow you :) Many thanks for the example. It helped me a lot!